# How do I change the difficulty?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I'm currently fighting the Maid of Windmere and she's ridiculously hard because she summons a dozen things to fight alongside her. Since I've tried to kill her about 30 times now, I think I'd like to be done with it and just move on. The best way I can think to do this is to change the difficulty (don't judge me). However, there's a problem: I can't find it. I've checked the options menu both in and out of game and I don't see a way to do it.

How do I change the difficulty in KoA?

Comment: Totally agree. Devs in general should rename *hard mode* to *spiteful mode* and *easy mode* to *enjoyable mode*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to set the difficulty in KoA.

**Start a New Game**

When you start a new game, you get to pick the difficulty.

Realistically, you're not very likely to abandon your game every time you want to change the difficulty

**From the Options Menu**

Go to the pause screen, then the *Options* menu. The difficulty controls are under gameplay options, which you can adjust at your leisure.

There do appear to be some conditions as to when you're allowed to change the difficulty (it might be as simple as, "cannot change while in combat", but I haven't been able to verify when it's disabled).

[image]

Comment: Wow...how in the world did I miss that?? Now I'm judging myself.

Comment: Even weirder, it wasn't there. I had to go out of the options menu and go back in for it to show up. Maybe a bug? Who knows.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the difficulty above "Hard" in any way? Or are there other ways to increase the perceived difficulty of the game without intentionally using bad gear?